# Nuget find reference in package folder but add it from another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, assemblies, .net-framework-version

I'm working on adding a new project to the existing solution in ASP.NET MVC. Everything goes fine until I update one of the packages. I found out that reference of "System.Net.Http" is pointing to a different location than I wanted to. This is how it looks like an object browser, I have 3 System.Net.Http Assemblies in different locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll (4.0.0.0)
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll (4.2.0.0)
- C:\MyProject\packages (4.1.1.1)

When I tried to reinstall the package via Nuget i got a message in Output console:

```
Found package 'System.Net.4.3.2' already exists in folder 'C:\MyProject\packages'
```

But when I looked in References of the project the path was to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual...".

Could someone explain to me why this happens? Why Nuget is saying that he finds the package in a specific folder but adds a reference to another? Also how to make him add references from "packages" if he finds one there?

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone explain to me why this happens? Why Nuget is saying that he finds the package in a specific folder but adds a reference to another? Also how to make him add references from "packages" if he finds one there?

That because `.NET Framework` supports `.NET Standard 2.0` starting from `4.6.1`,

> those packages (`System.net`, `System.Threading.Tasks.DataFlow`, etc)
>   have a `netstandard2.0` build. When a `netstandard2.0` assembly is
>   referenced in the desktop project, **nuget team automatically add all
>   the assemblies needed to make it work: no more package references**.
>   When nuget team add a newer `System.Net.Http.dll` than what you were
>   previously using, since that is part of netstandard2.0.

To resolve this issue, you could manually add binding redirect:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>
```

You can check following threads for some more details:

[System.Net.Http v4.2.0.0 being copied/loaded from MSBuild tooling](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773)

[Issues with .NET Standard 2.0 with .NET Framework & NuGet](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the DLL might have been added manually.

You should try to reinstall all yout NuGet :

```
Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName <yourproject>
```

But make sure your solution is up-to-date and you have no change with against GIT/SVN version-control for it might change a lot of things.